# How to plot graph of 2 list plots?

Tags: plotting

I have two Listsoflist containing x and y coordinates. Now, I want to plot the two profiles, show their intersection and find the area of each intersecting region. I have used interpolating function to find the plots but unable find intersection point.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the two lists, so that we can use them in the answer?

Comment: Then create a fake test case for us that has the same structrure, but is smaller.

Comment: This is one of your first posts and I'm going to create data for you, but you should really provide a sample of your data for allowing SE community to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating fake data for example

```
list1 = {Range[20],Join[Range[10] + RandomReal[1, 10],10 - Range[10] + RandomReal[1, 10]]}//Transpose;
list2 = {Range[20],Join[10 - Range[10] + RandomReal[1, 10], Range[10] + RandomReal[1, 10]]}//Transpose;
```

Interpolating them:

```
f1 = Interpolation[list1];
f2 = Interpolation[list2];
```

Finding intersections:

```
roots = {FindRoot[f1[x] - f2[x] == 0, {x, 5}], 
   FindRoot[f1[y] - f2[y] == 0, {y, 15}]} // Flatten
```

> {x -> 5.12575, y -> 14.9835}

Showing the plot:

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[{list1, list2}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {LightBlue, Transparent}}}]
 ,
 ListPlot[{{x, f1[x]}, {y, f1[y]}} /. roots, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

> [image]

Integrating for finding the area:

```
NIntegrate[f1[z] - f2[z], {z, x, y} /. roots]
```

> 50.5077